# Not solvable question civil engineering

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering

They didn’t give me the radius of the wheel where external force F is acting .

How can I calculate the reactions at A,B .

When they didn’t give me the radius .

Is this question “ Wrong “ ?

Note the force F in the right down wheel

Can someone confirm that $ A_y = 0 , B_y = F $

[image: Question 4]

Comment: Hard to tell what the question author had in mind. I would guess that they meant for the radius to be neglected. I. E. Assume it is zero. But that's just a guess. For anything definite you have to ask your instructor or whoever gave you the question

Comment: I agree. If it's not given then assume (and state this in your answer) that the radius of the pulley is small in comparison with *a* and can be ignored.

Comment: If it’s zero then the reaction $A_{y}=0$  ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Well I had to scratch my head on this one and dust off more than a few cobwebs.  Now my understanding is that if you put a pulley on the ceiling and pass a rope through it to a 100 lbs weight and you hold that weight you are pulling on the free end of the rope with 100 lbs.  If you are pulling straight down, it means you are are putting 100 lbs and the block is pulling down at 100 lbs and the pulley is exerting 200 lbs on the ceiling.

If you are pulling parallel to the ceiling then there is a 100 lbs down force and a 100 lbs horizontal force. or if you prefer a 141.4 lbs force at 45 degrees downward from the ceiling.

If my understanding is not valid, then the rest of this answer is not valid.

So I dropped this problem into S-Frame and placed the sum of the component horizontal and vertical loads as nodal loads.  Because I can't just put 'a' in as a length I opted to make 'a' 10.

Now provided my understanding of pulleys is correct, then this model confirms there is no vertical load at A (point 1)

[image: S-Frame Model]

This is with the understanding that the vertical and horizontal components of th e 45 degree line break into roughly 70.7107 each

Sum of forces at point 7 is:

```
Fy=100 down from vertical + 70.7107 down from diagonal
Fx=70 right from diagonal
```

Sum of forces at point 4 is:

```
Fy=100 up from vertical
```

Sum of forces at point 5 is:

```
Fy= 100 down from vertical + 70.7107 up from diagonal 
Fx= 70.7107 left from diagonal
```

Answer (score 0):

We have the force $ (\sqrt  2/2)* F \ $ acting horizontally to the right at point H and horizontally to the left at point E , both horizontal components of the cord tension, F making a moment of $ \ M=(\sqrt  2/2)* F*a .$

Now we equate sum of moments about A to zero and find reaction at B.

$$  \Sigma M_A =0 \quad= \frac{(\sqrt  2/2)* F*a + F*2a}{2a} +R_B = 0 $$

$$ -R_B=F+ \sqrt  2/4* F $$

We ignored the radius of pulley as implied by absence of it in the diagram

---

**Edit**

After checking my answer I realized there was an arithmetic error. So I used the simple way of just summing the moments about A to simplify it.

We have two forces acting on the system: $Fv \quad and \ F_{diagonal}$

$$  \Sigma M_A=0 \quad F* \frac{(3 \sqrt 2* a)}{2*2a}+ 
F* \frac{2a}{2a}+R_b=0 $$
Note:$  (3 \sqrt2/2*a)= \text{distance from A to  F(diag).}$

$  -R_b= 3 *\sqrt 2/4*F+F $

$ R_A=3 *\sqrt 2/4*F  $

Note: The sign reversal between the reactions indicates uplift reaction on A.

We ignored the radius of pulley as implied by absence of its dimension in the diagram. Please check my arithmetic.

Comment: You could simplify the answer further to be Rb = -F(1+sqrt(2)/4) = -F(4+sqrt(2))/4.

Comment: But why did you ignore the vertical components of the two pulleys

Comment: Also should the reaction $ R_B = F $ upwards since the only external force acting in the system is F downwards and $ R_A = 0 $

Comment: I tried your way taking into account the vertical components I get the same result $R_B = F $

Comment: @nick012000 are you sure your answer right ? Because I don’t think you calculated it right neglecting vertical forces. ~Nick012000

Comment: @RaziAwad I just took the equation that this answer presented as your final answer and simplified it with basic algebra. First you just simplify F + (sqrt(2)/4) F to F (1+ sqrt(2)/4), then multiply both sides by -1, so that Rb is positive. Optionally then convert 1 into 4/4 so that it can be combined with sqrt(2)/4 to make 1 + sqrt (2)/4 into (4 + sqrt (2))/4.

Comment: @nick012000 I think it should be $ R_B = F $ the only external force acting is the one in the graph . All the other Polly’s / lines are internal forces so : $\sum M_{A} = F* 2a - R_{B}* 2a = 0$

Comment: @RaziAwad No, there's also the forces and torques acting on the contraption through its connections to the floor, otherwise it'd start spinning in a clockwise direction and sinking into the floor, rather than remaining fixed in place.

Comment: I made the equation up after editing I checked everything It really seems right why is it wrong

Comment: The external forces : Reactions at $A$ , Reactions at $B$ , the force $F$ .

Comment: What System are you referring . My system is the whole construction

Comment: @nick012000   Why didn’t you take the vertical force of the Polly’s : $ N_{HE}^{y} $ the 2 Polly’s vertical component make overall momentum at A which is $\frac{Fa}{\sqrt(2)}$

Comment: @RaziAwad I was just performing algebraic manipulation on the final equation in  their answer, that being -Rb = F + (sqrt(2)/4) F. This equation would indicate a single force in the opposite direction of F. If there was a difference in direction, you would either need to include complex terms to denote the orthogonal force, or add in another equation to include either the orthogonal force or the direction that the force was being projected in.

Comment: @nick012000 but the equation itself is wrong it is missing moments because your system is the construction without the pulleys that’s why you took the moment of the horizontal components of the polleys . Now when you also take the vertical components you get the same equation as mine .

Comment: @RaziAwad, The system has only two external forces, F vertical at E and F diagonal at H. The H vertical downward component is handled by the cord going down vertically which is pulling up the beam and is internal. Its horizontal component is supported by an equal and opposite force on GH, takin the moments of this force about E gives the clockwise moment. and that's why we have negative reaction on A. it tends to lift up.

Comment: @kamran the cord $ HD$ doesn’t have equal force in opposite direction to the vertical component of H diagonal . $ GH$ Makes two forces axial and vertical . You assumed that it only makes axial force which is wrong .

Comment: @kamran I added answer with picture can you tell me what’s wrong with the answer . Note newton third law the forces are opposite .

Comment: @kamran I still think the answer is wrong , I will go with $ R_B = F , R_A = 0 $  I will put the final answers when the instructor put them . Thanks for your help